# Dynamic Javascript HTML ID Not Found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using javascript to dynamically create `td` elements. I'm assigning ids coming from a for loop. I can't fire off my onclick because it's throwing and error that the id can't be found. If I inspect the page, it's there.

```
var button_pressed_yes = 'rec_btn_yes_'+i;
var tempTd = '<td  class="cust-data-row-yes" style="height:40px;width:10%;  id="rec_btn_yes_' +i+'"  onclick="addYes('+button_pressed_yes+')" >';

$(".custDataWindow1").append(tempTd);
```

In my JS:

```
    function addYes(btnname){   
    alert("hello from button " + btnname);  
}
```

Error:

> (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: rec_btn_yes_2 is not defined
>       at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick

Comment: It looks like your `addYes()` function is trying to add an additional click handler to the same element that has the inline `onclick=` handler. If so, that doesn't make sense: it should just call `alert()` directly. Also, you don't need to pass the element ID to allow selecting the element because you already have a reference to the element if you pass `this`.

Comment: there's a fundamental flaw in your logic - once you fix the issue with the missing `"` for the style, and the quotes required for the function call, every time you click that cell, you will add another click event handler to that cell

Comment: simplest solution ... `onclick="addYes(this)"` and change addYes to work with an element rather than an ID ... and once you've sorted that out, re-think the whole process, as there is no logical reason to do what you are doing

Comment: Yes really what I need is the actual id number being passed in. Originally all I was passing was `i`. It may look redundant the way I showed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose `button_pressed_yes` in quotes to pass it as a string:

```
var button_pressed_yes = 'rec_btn_yes_'+i;
var tempTd = '<td  class="cust-data-row-yes" style="height:40px;width:10%;  id="rec_btn_yes_' +i+'"  onclick="addYes(\''+button_pressed_yes+'\')" >';

$(".custDataWindow1").append(tempTd);
```

Right now, the onclick generated would have a generated value something similar to below:

```
onclick="addYes(rec_btn_yes_2)"
```

`rec_btn_yes_2` the variable, doesn't exist. This is why you need to pass it as a string, so the generated result looks like:

```
onclick="addYes('rec_btn_yes_2')"
```

Comment: Yes this fixed the error I see now. However, the on click is not firing. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: `style="height:40px;width:10%;  id` - see how there's a `"` missing?